# How to install wkhtmltopdf on Ubuntu 16.04 (armhf)

Tags: 16.04, php, pdf, debian, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to install [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) on my Ubuntu 16.04 [scaleway](https://www.scaleway.com/) server. I've found [this](https://gist.github.com/brunogaspar/bd89079245923c04be6b0f92af431c10) tutorial online on how to install it. The problem is I'm stuck at step 3:

[image]

I'm getting the following error:

```
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing archive wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb (--
install):
package architecture (amd64) does not match system (armhf)
Errors were encountered while processing:
wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

Anybody can help me install this?

Comment: Sorry but you can not install amd/64-bit versions of software on a system that supports armhf. Find the correct debian installer (for armhf) and it will install. Oh and see the 1st lines on the read me you linked: tested on ... does not include armhf.

Comment: It's also up-to-date for armhf package architecture in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @karel, what do they mean with "In Ubuntu 16.04 and later wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2+ can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories."?

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, open the terminal and type `sudo apt install wkhtmltopdf` and you're done. wkhtmltopdf packages for armhf are available in the Ubuntu 16.04 repos.

Comment: I'm using this library: https://github.com/NitMedia/wkhtml2pdf. But I'm getting the error: vendor/nitmedia/wkhtml2pdf/src/Nitmedia/Wkhtml2pdf/lib/wkhtmltopdf-amd64. Am I using the wrong library?

Comment: @nielsv yes and follow Karels method. It is in the repo's it seems :)